# Для чего надо столько алгоритмов сортировки?

Tags: сортировка, алгоритм

Есть куча эффективных алгоритмов сортировки, навскидку помню : Хоара, Слиянием, Пирамидальная. Кто-то устойчив, кто-то нет. Для каких целей их так много?

Comment: Ну например один алгоритм работает более эффективно с мелкими массивами данных, другой наоборот - с большими. Один алгоритм используется для обучения, а другой уже в продакшене.

Comment: У верблюда два горба, потому что жизнь - борьба.

Comment: @voipp, если интересно поиграться (в Linux), то [можете скачать](http://code.google.com/p/yamsort/downloads/list).

Одно время я тоже увлекся этой темой. Там "измеритель" (его нужно править для задания разных наборов данных) и довольно много разных быстрых сортировок.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

А зачем нужно столько разных моделей телефонов или машин? По той же причине. Кому то нужна чуточку выше, кому-то, чуточку легче.

С алгоритмами сортировки такая же история. Разные люди придумывали свои алгоритмы для своих специфических задач. Одни алгоритмы хороши для больших объемов, другие - для почти отсортированных данных, третьи, когда есть много памяти или когда памяти впритык.

- [И снова про сортировки: выбираем лучший алгоритм](http://habrahabr.ru/post/133996/)
- [Алгоритмы и структуры данных — шпаргалка](http://habrahabr.ru/post/156361/)

Answer (score 1):

Ответ - потому что. Дело в том, что есть разные ситуации. В каких-то ситуациях нет ограничений на время или на кол-во потребляемой памяти при сортировке. В некоторых случаях необходимо, чтобы объекты сортировались с учетом исходной последовательности (это и есть устойчивость сортировки). Иногда требуется, чтобы сортировка была максимально быстрой, при этом есть какие особенности во входных данных. Учитывая, что компьютер "тупой", то программист должен ему подсказать какой алгоритм выбрать в каждом конкретном случае. Поэтому и нужно знать разные алгоритмы и их слабые и сильные стороны, чтобы выбрать необходимый для решения конкретной задачи.